# WordPress Custom Post Type Infinite Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, infinite-loop, custom-post-type

I am using WP_query for my custom post type archive page, and the query seems to be stuck in the infinite loop.

---

**archive.php**

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'faqs',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $faqs_loop = get_template_part('loop-faqs');
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

**loop.php**

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#<?php the_id(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <div id="<?php the_id(); ?>" class="accordion-section-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What makes you say there is an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

u cant do a infinity loop in webb it just load to the browser crash or stop the prosses